# Getting a permgen error while running easyb\selenium

Tags: ant, selenium, jenkins, gradle, easyb

I have 6 technologies in play

easyB
Selenium
Gradle
Ant
Java
Jenkins

We use **easyB** to write scenarios
Those scenarios in turn invoke **Selenium**
Finally we use **Gradle** to kick start all stories.
And since we do not have a gradle plugin for easyB, gradle really uses **ant** to run easyB.

This Gradle script is finally executed via a **Jenkins** job

The complete execution takes about **3-4 hours**.
Half-way through, we get a **perm-gen error**

I am not sure **which process needs the increase** in PermGen

EasyB ?
Ant?
Gradle?

---

**Error Message**
[ant:easyb] retry value is now: 2
[ant:easyb] objectID is set to:   60868
[ant:easyb] break after creating subjectID 60868
[ant:easyb] Creating visit>>>>>>Pre Treatment
[ant:easyb] Creating Image Group>>>>>>auto-gp1
[ant:easyb] There was an error running your easyb story or specification
[ant:easyb] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[ant:easyb] easyb execution FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

---

**Gradle script**

```
check << {
    def script = new GroovyShell()
    script.run(new File('InitializeReport.groovy'))

    ant.taskdef(name: "easyb", classname:"org.easyb.ant.BehaviorRunnerTask", classpath: sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath)

    ant.easyb( classpath: sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath, failureProperty:'easyb_failed' ,tags:tags) {
        report( location:"${project.testResultsDir}/story."+format, format:format )
        behaviors( dir: storiesHome ) {
            include( name:storyToBeExecuted )
        }
   }

    ant.fail( if:'easyb_failed', message: 'Failures in easyb stories' )
}
```

---

This is what I see on the Jenkins console
Note- how the memory options are being passed to the Gradle command , but not to the Java command which is running the easyB scripts ? 
**That is where- I think the problem is...**

[jenkins@bil-dev-006v bin]$ ps -ef|grep gradle

jenkins  18420  4714  9 23:04 ?        00:00:16 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=700m -Xmx512m **-XX:MaxPermSize=800m** -Xmx512m -classpath /opt/jenkins/gradle-1.0-milestone-1/lib/gradle-launcher-1.0-milestone-1.jar -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain -PstoryName= -PstoriesHome= check -info

jenkins  18579 18420 13 23:04 ?        00:00:21 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20/jre/bin/java -classpath /jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/build/classes/main:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/xml-apis.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/activation.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/xercesSamples.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/safe-client.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/security.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/http-builder-0.5.1.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/safe-import.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/mail.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/ojdbc14.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/xercesImpl.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/cacher.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/serializer.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/resolver.jar:/jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/lib/cache-verifier.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/org.easyb/easyb/jars/easyb-0.9.7.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/commons-cli/commons-cli/jars/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.7.2.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/org.seleniumhq.selenium.client-drivers/selenium-java-client-driver/jars/selenium-java-client-driver-1.0.1.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/log4j/log4j/bundles/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-1.8.2.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/antlr/antlr/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/asm/asm/jars/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/asm/asm-commons/jars/asm-commons-3.2.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/asm/asm-tree/jars/asm-tree-3.2.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/asm/asm-util/jars/asm-util-3.2.jar:/opt/jenkins/.gradle/cache/asm/asm-analysis/jars/asm-analysis-3.2.jar org.easyb.BehaviorRunner -outfail failed.txt -html /jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/build/test-results/storycaseassigment_inter-intra.html /jenkins/jobs/helium-complete-run/workspace/trunk/src/test/stories/caseassigment/inter-intra/ca_interintra.story

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the perm gen space, you can do this by setting the max parameter through the VM settings. On the command line, start Java with the following option:

> -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

See also: http://www.freshblurbs.com/explaining-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space

Comment: For which process? Ant?gradle?EasyB ?

Comment: Whichever process is causing the error. It wouldn't harm to set it for all!

Answer (score 0):

The way you've implemented it, the easyB tests will run in the "main" Gradle JVM (unless the easyB Ant task forks a new JVM, which I doubt.)   One way to pass JVM options to that process is via the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable:

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
```

Other ways to set this option are `properties.gradle` (see [Gradle user guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3agradle_properties_and_system_properties) for details) or tweaking the `gradlew` script (if you happen to use the Gradle wrapper).

Comment: I did add GRADLE_OPTS to my env variable- that didn't seem to help. I guess I can try other alternate ways ...

Comment: Either you made a mistake in setting the environment variable, or the easyB Ant task forks a new JVM. I can't find any indication for the latter. With a tool like `ps` on *nix or Process Explorer on Windows, you can easily check which command-line arguments are passed to the Gradle process, and whether `-XX:MaxPermSize` is among them.

Comment: I am getting closer.. I can see that the Gradle process is in fact getting the Memory options (I had to edit the gradle script) But the EasyB script launched from Gradle- is not being passed the memory options.

Comment: So it seems like the easyB Ant task _does_ in fact create a new process, which makes this a pure easyB (Ant task) question. I didn't see a way to pass memory options to that Ant task, but better ask on the easyB list.

Comment: OK- I think I am finally getting there- it's not Gradle which is spawning the second process. But the Ant task.... If that's the case- you are right it would be a Q for easyB list. Thanks for all your help and patience.